# TIdTCPServer sharing of serial port

Tags: c++, sockets, c++builder, indy

Recently I changed a program which acts as a TCP server to help share the traffic on a serial port connected to a device. Multiple clients connect and should have access to the Serial Port and act simultaneously.

Application is built using C++Builder, using `TIdTCPServer` in the server and `TIdTCPClient` in the client application.

Multiple clients need to connect and send commands to the serial port.  The serial port will respond immediately after sending a command to it, as per the protocols of the device it is attached to.

There is also a background thread which occasionally accesses the serial port and updates a memory cache of data held in the server's memory.  The commands for sending and receiving from the serial port have a mutex on them, so they are accessible from both the `TIdTcpServer`'s `OnExecute` event and the background thread.

I'm having difficulty getting the `TIdTCPServer`'s `OnExecute` event to work without overlapping.

It would be really nice if the `OnExecute` event were to execute fully without another request coming in from another client, causing the overlapping.

Here is the `OnExecute` event handler of the `TIdTCPServer`:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::IServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    int  i;
    int Len;
    TIdBytes TRB, TSB;
    unsigned char ARB[BUFFERLENGTH];
    int NumbSent, NumbReceived;

    // Read the command from the client.  Send the length first then the actual data.
    Len = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLongInt();
    AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadBytes(TRB, Len, false);

    memset(ARB,0,BUFFERLENGTH);
    for(i=0;i<Len;i++) AOB[i]=TRB[i];

    NumbSent=Len;


    // Now send it out to the Serial port
    ProcessSerialMessage(AOB, Len, ARB, &NumbReceived, false);

    sending=false;

    TSB.Length=NumbReceived;
    for(i=0;i<TSB.Length;i++) TSB[i]=ARB[i];
    AContext->Connection->Socket->Write(TSB.Length);
    AContext->Connection->Socket->Write(TSB);

    return;
}
```

Here is the routine for sending the data out over the serial port:

```cpp
int ProcessSerialMessage(unsigned char *SendBuf, int NumbSBytes, unsigned char *ReceiveBuf, int *NumbRBytes, bool CalledFromThread)
{

    // MMUtex is a global TMutex Object
    // Mutex required to help with the background thread trying to update memory cache.
    MMutex->Acquire();


    // Ok now send the data out over the serial port and receive it.
    // These routines are standard serial port I/O routines and aren't explained here.
    rawsend(SendBuf, NumbSBytes);
    rawreceive(ReceiveBuf, NumbRBytes);

    RetValue=*NumbRBytes;
    MMutex->Release();

    return(RetValue);
}
```

Comment: Hi Remy.  I was hoping you would answer my question as I see you are one of the authorities on this component.  I tried sending you an email from your web site but couldn't because the Captcha on your site fails every time I try.

Comment: Anyways,  I am having unpredictable results when I have 2 or more clients attached and siimultaneously trying to access the serial port at the same time.  I would like to put together a PDF file and send it to you for you to look at as I will have to take a few snapshots of the screens for you to visualize what is going on.  Is there a way in which I can email them to you?

Comment: Where is your `AOB` variable declared? In the code shown, it is not a local variable, like `ARB` is. Which means it Isa shared variable that is not being protected from concurrent access. Why are you not passing your `TRB` and `TSB` arrays directly to `ProcessSerialMessage()`? The loops to copy bytes from one array to another are not necessary, thus you can eliminate `AOB` and `ARB`. That might solve your isuue.

Comment: Its declared globally.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Then you have a concurrency conflict when reading in your client data. I have posted an answer about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component. Each connected client runs in its own independent thread. The `OnExecute` event runs in those threads. So, it is your responsibility to make sure your `OnExecute` code is thread-safe, by serializing access to any shared resources.

You are using a mutex inside of `ProcessSerialMessage()`, so you are serializing access to the serial port (assuming your other background thread is also entering the same mutex). So that should be fine (although, I would suggest protecting the mutex locking/unlocking using a `try..__finally` block, or a local RAII-style class, to ensure the mutex is unlocked properly even if an exception is thrown).

However, one major issue I see with this code is that your `AOB` (and `sending`) variable is not declared as a local variable to `IServerExecute()`, which means it must be a shared variable accessed across threads (UPDATE: you have confirmed that in comments: "*[AOB is] declared globally.*"). But, it is not being protected from concurrent access by multiple threads, which means that multiple clients are free to overwrite each other's inbound data while it is being sent to the serial port.

You are reading the serial port's response into local  variables, and then using them to send back to the requesting clients. So there is no concurrency issue in that code.

I would suggest passing your `TRB` and `TSB` arrays directly to `ProcessSerialMessage()`. The 2 loops you have to copy bytes from one array to another are not really necessary, thus you can eliminate the `AOB` and `ARB` variables from this code completely. That might be enough to solve your issue.

Try this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::IServerExecute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    TIdBytes TRB, TSB;
    int NumbSent, NumbReceived;

    // Read the command from the client.  Send the length first then the actual data.
    NumbSent = AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadLongInt();
    AContext->Connection->Socket->ReadBytes(TRB, NumbSent, false);

    TSB.Length = BUFFERLENGTH;

    // Now send it out to the Serial port
    ProcessSerialMessage(&TRB[0], NumbSent, &TSB[0], &NumbReceived, false);

    AContext->Connection->Socket->Write(NumbReceived);
    AContext->Connection->Socket->Write(TSB, NumbReceived);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Remy!!!!  Its working perfectly now.  Even though I didn't post all the source code, it was the definition of the buffers that was messing it up.  Fixed it up and all is well.  Thanks for your help!!!!

Comment: Remy,  just out of curiosity, when dealing with a serial port in this manner, what is the proper way to close the TIdTCPServer component IF there are still active clients attached to it?  I have put code in my client applications to check for this and will stop all communications if it happens.  However, in the server, simply putting TIdTCPServer->Active=false causes the server to hang.

Comment: "*in the server, simply putting `TIdTCPServer->Active=false` causes the server to hang*" - the `Active` property setter is synchronous. When setting it to false, it does not exit until all clients are disconnected and the server is fully deactivated. If you deactivate the server in the main thread, and then try to synchronize with the main thread while it is waiting for the deactivation to finish, that is a deadlock situation. So, either don't sync with the main thread while it is deactivating the server, or else move the deactivation to a separate thread so the main thread is not blocked.

Comment: Remy, Can you give me an example of how to work around this?  I have tried the following and it doesn't work:
```
ClientList = IServer->Contexts->LockList();

try {
    for (i = 0; i < ClientList->Count; i++) {
        MyContext = (TIdContext*) ClientList->Items[i];
        MyContext->Connection->Disconnect();

     }
    }

__finally {
    IServer->Contexts->UnlockList();
   }



try {
 IServer->Active=false;
 }
catch(...) {

 }
```

Comment: Not without seeing your actual code that is hanging. Do you have `OnConnect`/`OnDisconnect` handlers assigned to the server, which sync with the main thread? Or, does your `OnExecute` handler do any syncing with the main thread? The `Active` property setter already `Disconnect`s clients for you. That is not the issue.

Comment: WHERE is that code being called from? And please answer my other questions, about the main thread syncing. I can't help you without seeing the bigger picture of what you are doing with the server

Comment: I do have handlers for the Server OnConnect / OnDisconnect but it only updates a counter in the GUI for the number of clients connected.  I am new to Indy so some of what you are saying is alien to me, particularly about the threads.

Comment: HOW do they update the GUI exactly? Is that a synchronized operation? Can you please update your question to show the actual code?

Comment: The code above, which for some reason isn't formatting, is from a button I press on the server to stop it from executing.

Comment: The OnConnect / OnDisconnect handlers are as follows:
```

void __fastcall TfrmMain::IServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
INumbConnections++;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TfrmMain::IServerDisconnect(TIdContext *AContext)
{
INumbConnections--;
}

Comment: That is not thread-safe, as you are not guaranteed atomic access to `INumbConnections` like that, so you need to serialize access to `INumbConnections`  instead (see `TIdThreadSafeInteger`, for instance). But in any case, WHERE and HOW are you actually updating the GUI to display `INumbConnections`? Does your server do ANYTHING ELSE that touches the GUI? Can you please just provide a [mcve] in your question instead of in comments?

Comment: GUI is updated by the INumbConnections variable in the ApplicationEvents component's OnIdle.

Comment: There is only 1 way that `Active=false` hangs - if the server's internal threads are not being terminated properly. And the only ways (that I know of) for that to happen are if either 1) your server event handlers are synchronizing with the main thread while it is blocked deactivating the server, or 2) your event handlers are blocking the threads from terminating, such as by catching and discarding Indy exceptions instead of letting the server process them. That is why I need you to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the hang in action. And that should be posted as a new question.

Comment: Remy,  I can send you some of the source but I won't post it all here due to security reasons.  Can you send me a message with your email address in it and I can send it there?

Comment: No, that is not how this site works. [mcve] - emphasis on **minimal** and **reproducible**. It doesn't have to be your *real* code, but it should be *representative* of what the real code does.  A few dozen lines at most should do. That can easily fit in a new question.

Comment: `code`void __fastcall TfrmMain::StopButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
int i;
int Result;
TIdContext *MyContext;
TList *ClientList;


ClientList = IServer->Contexts->LockList();

try {
    for (i = 0; i < ClientList->Count; i++) {
        MyContext = (TIdContext*) ClientList->Items[i];
        MyContext->Connection->Disconnect();

     }
    }

__finally {
    IServer->Contexts->UnlockList();
   }
try {
 IServer->Active=false;  // Server hangs here
 }
catch(...) {

 }
return;
}

Comment: Why can't I format this code in the comments?

Comment: ```void __fastcall TfrmMain::ApplicationEvents1Idle(TObject *Sender, bool &Done)
{
int NumbConnections;
int NumbMonitorPoints;


NumbConnections=INumbConnections;
NumbConnect->Caption=IntToStr(NumbConnections);
if(NumbConnections==0)  InitializeMonitorCache();
return;
}
```

Comment: Please stop putting code in comments, it belongs as edits to your original question instead (or better, as a new question, since this issue has NOTHING to do with the serial port issue, which has been answered). But what you have shown is not a [mcve] since you have not shown any logic for the server events, especially anything that is touching the UI.

Comment: Remy, I found a solution in another thread.  Simply set the OnDisconnect event to NULL and parse through the connections and close them.  When the server starts, I set the OnDisconnect event to what I had before.  This works perfectly.

Comment: That implies your `OnDisconnect` handler is doing something it should not be doing, but you have not shown that code. Under normal conditions, you should not have to set any event to NULL to make this work properly. And you certainly don't need to close the connections manually, like I said the `Active` property setter already handles that for you.

Comment: Remy,  I posted another question on Stackoverflow.com regarding creating SQL Server *.MDF files.  If you have a moment, can you please take a look at it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69316572/creating-sql-server-mdf-file-using-c-builder-and-adox

Comment: @Drewski7280 I already saw that question earlier and chose not to answer it (I'm not a database dev). In any case, that question about ADOX has absolutely nothing to do with this question about Indy, so please don't cross-post like this again.